# Relation $\rho$ such that $a = bn$ not anti-symmetric?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have a homework question that asks me to determine determine whether given relations are reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric,
asymmetric or transitive.

One relation is:

$\rho \subseteq \mathbb \times \mathbb Z$, where $a~\rho~b$ if and only if there is $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a = bn$

The answer says it's reflexive and transitive. How come is it not anti-symmetric?

We only find $x~\rho~y$ and $y~\rho~x$ if $x = y$.

*like in (1,1) or (2,2)*.

Comment: Domain is integers, not natural numbers: $(1,-1)$ as well as $(-1,1)$.

Comment: thank you this is it! You can put it as an answer (as a counter example that proves anti-symmetry false) @HendrikJan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a=0,b=5$. Then $a~\rho~b$ (take $n=0$) and $b~\rho~a$ (take $n=0$). However, $a\neq b$.

Antisymmetry requires that if $a~\rho~b$ and $b~\rho~a$ for some $a,b$, it must hold that $a=b$. Since the antecedent is true in the above example, but the consequent is not, $\rho$ cannot be antisymmetric.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/686588)

Comment: @Qwerty it does provide an answer; it shows why $\rho$ is not antisymmetric by providing a counter argument. I will edit to make that clearer.